# Drools accumulate

Tags: function, drools, accumulate

Could someone please help me with this accumulate function accumulate

```
($sum: Repetition(objectId == getEventKey(), "VERY_LONG".equals(getRepType())); 
  $count: count($sum); $count== $vlongCount)
```

though the `$count=10 and vlongcount=11` accumulate is still happening. is there any bug associted with accumulate function in Drools

Comment: From what you have posted I cannot even try to guess your intention. Add the Java code for class `Repetition`, the complete rule text and how you insert  facts. Don't forget to state the Drools version number.

Comment: hi the drools version is 6.0.3.

Comment: Hi the drools version is 6.0.3  ..From Repetiton class im trying to accumulate some data based on some conditions.  so im counting the $sum variable..  then trying to compare with Vlongcount that was recieved before.

Comment: here is the rule                                                                                         rule "abc"
    when
    $rep: Repetition(eventId:getEventID(),,$shtcnt: Integer.valueOf(((ALA)getObject()).getALACOUNT()),"VERY_LONG_REP".equals(getRepType())) 
    accumulate($sum: Repetition(objectId == getEventKey(), "VERY_LONG".equals(getRepType()));$count: count($sum); $count== $vlongCount)
    then

Comment: class Repetition { 
public String eventID; 
 private String eventKey; 
 Object object; 
 private String repType;
 public String getEventID() {
  return eventID;
 }
 
 public String getEventKey() {
  return eventKey;
 }
  public Object getObject() {
  return object;
 }
 
 public String getRepType() {
  return repType;
 }
 

}

Comment: No. Please edit your question. Comments aren't intended for posting code. If the full rule code refers to classes other than `Repetition` (ALA??) you should posts these, too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$count:Number(intValue == $vlongCount)
from accumulate(Repetition($sum: objectId == getEventKey(), "VERY_LONG".equals(getRepType())),$count: count($sum))
```